# Using Netscape library for performing LDAP search operation and getting limited result upto 10000 when range is provided (0-*)

Tags: ldap, ads, openldap, adam, netscape

I am using Netscape library for performing search operation on microsoft ADS/ADAM Ldap server
Following is the snippet I am using:

```
LDAPConnection connection=new LDAPConnection();
connection.connect("xx.xx.xx.xx", 389);
connection.authenticate( "CN=xx,CN=xx,DC=xx,DC=xx,DC=xx", "xxxx");
String[] attr= { "member;range=0-*" };
        
LDAPSearchResults resultSet = connection.search("CN=UsersGroup,CN=Builtin,DC=xx,DC=xx,DC=xx", 2, "(&(objectclass=group))", attr,false);
```

API is returning only 10000 records for "member" multivalued attribute.

MaxValRange value is set to 50000 on server.

Is there any way I can get more than 10K records in single search?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFIK, besides modifying the MaxValRange, you need to override the upper-limits introduced in Windows Server 2008/R2 and restore the old-style (no upper limit enforced behavior for LDAP Query Policy in Windows Server 2003), modify the [dSHeuristic attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/qzaidi/override-the-hardcoded-ldap-query-limits-introduced-in-windows-server-2008-and-windows-server-2008-r2) in Active Directory.

And of course you could use the [Ranging OID](https://ldapwiki.com/wiki/LDAP_SERVER_RANGE_OPTION_OID).

We did, sometime ago, create some [Example Java code](https://ldapwiki.com/wiki/LDAP_SERVER_RANGE_OPTION_OID_CODE_SAMPLE) to make the process easier.

Comment: Hi jwilleke,
I am using Windows Server 2012 R2.
Same is applicable for Windows Server 2012 R2?

Comment: AFIK, for any Windows server after Windows Server 2008/R2.

Comment: I added some links to sample code to implement ranging options.

Comment: I don't see option "dSHeuristic" in attribute list on Windows server 2012 R2.

Comment: Hi jwilleke, Your suggestion helped solving my problem. I have added "dSHeuristic" attribute to the list and now i am able to fetch records more than 10K. Thanks for your help.